# I want to print the string between two strings which has special characters using python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Below is the complete text from which i want to retrieve the text between "
General Comment text : " and "Setup done by :"

Text:

DONE
The C-Arm Test cell humidity in % RH is:
Observed value : 25

General Comment text :

{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg936\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}

{*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\lang1033\f0\fs20 No measurements were taken\par

}

Setup done by : 502184520
Setup done on : 03/24/16

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] . In other words, please show your code attempt for this and provide necessary details.

Comment: You question really needs to get edit ..!

Comment: r"General Comment text :(.*)Setup done by" with flags for `dotall` and `multiline` would work. 
But it looks real ugly. 
We need more context...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP seems to be asking to write for him the code instead of support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, you may even do without regular expressions.

```
s = """
DONE The C-Arm Test cell humidity in % RH is: Observed value : 25

General Comment text :

{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg936\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}

{*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\lang1033\f0\fs20 No measurements were taken\par

}

Setup done by : 502184520 Setup done on : 03/24/16
"""

start = "General Comment text :\n"
end = "\nSetup done by :"

print(s.split(start)[1].split(end)[0])
```